# Necessity of applying encoding gamma when taking Bayer RGB from sensor to JPEG

Tags: image, colors

This is a colour space/ gamma encoding question

I am taking images from a raw 5MP Image sensor. This sensor produces 8 Bit RGB Bayer, and has Auto White Balance and Auto Gain, but does not do colour space conversion/ gamma  on the sensor (other versions of this sensor do).

According to the theory, both from the manufacturer and the Internet, (see wikipedia for 'color image pipeline')  there should be an encoding gamma correction of the image in the color pipeline before I convert to Y'Cb'Cr' and JPeg

If I take the RAW RGB Bayer images, and then load them in Irfanview (which demosaics) and save as BMP, then the results I am getting (before applying gamma) look like this  http://flic.kr/p/bCWz5n and this http://flic.kr/p/bq2CD1.  (FLickr has downsampled but I assume doesn't affect the colour space). As far as I can tell these images don't need gamma encoding correction - If I apply .45 (encoding) they become too dark, 2.2 (decoding) they get washed out. There may be other colour balance issues.

So my question is

a) Is there some reason I don't need to apply gamma

b) Have I missed something (e.g. does irfanview demosaic also apply a gamma correction - I have looked at this and think it doesn't - when I look at the raw values of RGB for a grey block in a colour chart I am getting individual  R,G,B approx 104,116,145 in the Bayer, and then in the BMP I am getting very similar values for the RGB triples after Saving as a BMP after the irfanview RAW import)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so the answer seems to be that encoding gamma is in the eye of the beholder. Current best results come from converting to YCbCr, altering the saturation by linearly increasing Cb Cr, and leaving the gamma alone. This works experimentally, but is unsatisfying as a full explanation